# Custom Actionbar shows margin

Tags: android, android-actionbar, customization

I am trying to create an android application with custom actionbar.

my code is

```
package com.sample.actionbar;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //displaying custom ActionBar
        View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_custom, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0C2640")));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.



        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But it shows margin on all sides.

[image]

I want it to fit with actionbar.
How can i remove this margin?
I tried many codes. but didnt gt what i want.

Comment: put your xml file of custom actionbar here. Look in to the file if by default margin is added by editor or not ? if margin is added there then remove from it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem. The solution for me was to add the following entries to my ActionBar style:

```
<item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
<item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
```

So the parts of my styles.xml related to it are resulting:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Actionbar</item>
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="Actionbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this way:

```
ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) contextAct.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_customview,null);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Top and bottom margins removed. still at start and end.

Comment: @SoniaJohn, Give match_parent widht & height to parent view of xml of action bar view.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use `Toolbar`. Create it in your layout xml file like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <!-- Your custom action bar views -->

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity just set the the `Toolbar` to be your action bar:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```